# Can't open most programs (.exe issue?)

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I'm having issues opening programs on my desktop! Everything initially started being super slow (>1min to open), then internet connectivity dropped, and now most programs won't open (or have issues).

Programs I can open (many slow/freeze): Edge, IE, Fraps, Soluto, Avast Antivirus

e.g. IE opens, but freezes within a minute

Programs I can't open: Steam, Skype, Malwarebytes, Razer Synapse

e.g. steam displays 'updating steam' then goes away and doesn't open

However, EVERYTHING works seamlessly when booted in safe mode.

I have already checked: GPU, Ram, malware/antivirus.

Possibly an .exe problem, but it doesnt match the symptoms of 'open with', and some .exe can be opened.

EDIT: internet now working again. Programs not opening and/or slow still an issue.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this helps,

Try to check if you have the user account control configuration as defaults when windows is installed,

I had some issues with this missconfiguration when trying to open default windows programs they las more than 5 min loading, like image viewer etc..

Cheers

Comment: The question isn't only about default Windows programs.